# Debug logging with React

Tags: javascript, debugging, reactjs

I'd like to:

1. insert debug logging statements into my code that I want to be able to turn on and off during development; and
2. then have these statements stripped out entirely in production.

To accomplish stripping out the logs for production, I've seen that the React project itself uses this idiom:

```
if ("production" !== process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    // warn or log or whatever
}
```

By compiling the modules with `process.env.NODE_ENV` set to `"production"` and then running the bundle through a dead code eliminator like UglifyJS, the logs will be eliminated as unreachable.

This is fine, but are there more flexible solutions? I'm thinking something like the `debug()` Node module, or really some even more powerful, like the Java logging APIs.

I am wondering why I'm not finding a module that combines the `("production" !== process.env.NODE_ENV)` approach with `debug()`.

Answer (score 11):

```
var debug = function(msg) {
    if ("production" !== process.env.NODE_ENV) console.log(msg);
}
module.exports = debug;
```

Usage:

```
var debug = require("debug");
debug("some logs");
```

Sorry, I couldn't help myself ;). But really, there are plenty of JS logging frameworks out there (although I honestly think the solution above is simple enough that you don't need to over-complicate things).

Comment: Haha yeah that's what I'm doing right now! I was just wondering because I'm not finding that in use anywhere else. Thinking maybe there's something better that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a Java world, I was pleased to see there is a 'log4javascript' project.

http://log4javascript.org/

It has some cool stuff including a logging console with some features...

[image]